# Inserting value into the middle of a double linked list

Tags: c, algorithm, list

I'm working in C and I'm trying to make a program that reads the lines from a file and sorts them into a double linked list. Currently I am able to read the file correctly, and before I added the sorting functionality the double linked list was recording the values as expected, but for some reason now that I'm trying to add values into the middle of the list instead of just the end the entire list is being over written with the most recent input. The following is my initialization of the data structure and the implementation of the insertion function. I'm using the ID parameter to sort the nodes, and in the end if I output the ID's they are in the correct order, it's just the data preserved in the val  variable (which is a line from the file) that doesn't save correctly. Thanks!

```
typedef struct ListNode {
    struct ListNode *next;
    struct ListNode *prev;
    char *val;
    int id;
} ListNode;

typedef struct List {
    int count;
    ListNode *first;
    ListNode *last;
} List;


void List_push(List *list, char *newval, int id)
{
    ListNode *node = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

    if(list->count >0) {
            printf("First in list is now %s", list->first->val);
    }

    node->val = newval;
    node->id = id;
    printf("This value is: %s The id is: %d\n", node->val, node->id);
    if(list->last == NULL) {
            printf("List is empty, inserting first element\n");
            list->first = node;
            list->last = node;
    }
    else if(node->id < list->first->id) {
            printf("Value is smaller than first in list\n");
            printf("First in list was %s \n", list->first->val);
            node->next = list->first;
            printf("%s is now second\n", node->next->val);
            list->first->prev = node;
            printf("First in list is now %s", list->first->prev->val);
            list->first = node;
            printf("First in list is now %s\n", list->first->val);
            printf("Then %s\n", list->first->next->val);
    }
    else {
            node->next = list->first;
            printf("Value bigger than first in list\n");
            int found = 0;
            while((node->next != NULL) && (found ==0)) {
                    if(node->id < node->next->id) {
                            found = 1;
                    }
else {
                            printf("Still looking\n");
                            printf("%d\n", node->next->id);
                            node->next = node->next->next;
                    }
            }
            if(found == 1) {
                    printf("Found location\n");
                    node->prev = node->next->prev;
                    node->next->prev = node;
                    printf("First in list: %d\n", list->first->id);
            }
            else {
                    list->last->next = node;
                    node->prev = list->last;
                    list->last = node;
            }
    }

    list->count++;
}
```

Comment: please show sample input and output.

Comment: Where does `newval` come from? Does it just point to your input buffer or have you made a copy of the input before calling `List_push`?

Comment: With a doubly-linked list, four pointers need to be set to insert an item between two items (one each from the existing items to point to the new item, and two in the new item to point to the existing items). In your last if/else I only see two and three pointers being updated. When debugging data structures like this, make a drawing that you update as the code runs (only change what the code changes; don't draw what you *think* should happen, only what *really does* and you'll find your bug).

Comment: "don't draw what you *think* should happen, only what *really does* and you'll find your bug" — how very zen of you @Dithermaster

Answer (score 0):

In the `Found location` block you forgot to set the `next` of the previous node; change

```
                node->next->prev = node;
```

to

```
                node->prev->next =
                node->next->prev = node;
```

there.

Answer (score 0):

The long an short of inserting a node into the middle of a linked list is like this:

1. You have a function that you pass in a VALID pointer to a node as the argument to.
2. You created a new node (`node_new`)
3. You set `node_new->next = node->next`
4. You set `node_new->prev = node`
5. You set `node->next = node_new`
6. IF `node_new->next` is NOT NULL, then you say `node_new->next->prev = node_new`; this is because if `node_new->next == NULL` then it does not have a `prev` field.

This is a VERY important check to make; if you do not you may encounter VERY STRANGE PROBLEMS!